# Executed shortcode nested inside another shortcode with PHP in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I don't know if I'm anywhere close to getting this to work, but I've been working on it for 3 hours now and though I've made progress, it's not working completely. I'm not that versed in PHP, so this has been a battle. Basically what I'm trying to do is this:

I'm using the Formidable Pro to capture two numbers from a user about a goal. The ID of the beginning number is 104. The ID of the goal in the form is 107.

Then on a separate page I'm using the http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/progress-bar/ plugin to measure progress on the goal.

I need to perform calculations on the beginning number and the goal number and have the result inputted into the progress-bar plugin.

I can't even get a number to show up in the progress bar, so I don't know what else to do.

This is what I have:

```
[wppb option=red percent=inside progress="<?php echo do_shortcode('[frm-stats id=\"107\"]'); ?>"]
```

I figured that if I could at least get a number to show up in the progress bar then I could figure out the calculation part of the code...

Any thoughts?

Comment: Wordpress does not support nested shortcodes, that's a limitation of that system (a feature that is not available).

Comment: @hakre Any tips then on how to do this?

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me where that code goes in that you create there. I think there is more code around what you posted.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to nest shortcodes right now. Maybe in the future.